# Failing to add a new line in Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, textbox, appendtext

I really appreciate your help and contribution in advance, I am training on C# home and it's been great way to do something with home time: I am trying to append a string of text to `txtCollectionBox` from `txtNoteBox` and a new line at the end of each string of text from `txtNoteBox`. But it's appending on the same line, not a new line - does anyone know why?

```
private void btnAddNote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtNoteBox.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Add a Note");
    }
    else
    {
        txtCollectionBox.AppendText("[*] " + txtNoteBox.Text + "  ." + "\n");
        txtNoteBox.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're appending the new note and _following_ that with a newline. Typically one would append a newline and then the new note.

Comment: The line break in C# is `\r\n`

Answer (score 3):

Try removing `\n` and replacing it with`Environment.NewLine`. (or maybe it is `System.Environment.NewLine` I don't remember.)

Comment: This worked System.Environment.NewLine, Thank you so much you are awesome!